# SQL Select specific values from another SQL query

Tags: sql

"F4111" is a table with detailed orders, where "SU" order types are output and "OU" order types are inputs. All "SU" orders are related to one specific "OU" order, so that the sum of all SU and OU orders should be zero. Their relationship is given by their ID. If SU orderID is 1000, then its OU related orderID is 1001. I have a SQL query that gives me some specific SU orders

```
SELECT F4111.orderID FROM F4111 F4111
WHERE F4111.orderDATE='2016/05/09' AND F4111.orderTYPE='SU' AND F4111.orderDESTINY='333333'
```

Now i need another query that gives me all the OU orders related to that specific SU orders, so i did this:

```
SELECT
F4111_1.orderID, 
F4111_1.orderTYPE, 
F4111_1.orderLINE, 
F4111_1.orderITEM,
F4111_1.orderQUANTITY
FROM F4111 F4111_1
WHERE
F4111_1.orderTYPE='OU' AND 
F4111_1.orderID in (SELECT DISTINCT (F4111.orderID+1) FROM F4111 F4111
WHERE F4111.orderDATE='2016/05/09' AND F4111.orderTYPE='SU' AND F4111.orderDESTINY='333333')
```

But this was very slow. It was faster to do N separate querys where N is the number of unique SU IDs given in the first query.

Any idea how to do this faster? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, first thing I notice is `distinct`, you don't need it in an `in` construction.

Comment: I deleted my old answer because my assumption was incorrect about your data.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without knowing things like what type of database this is, what indices are on the table, and the number of rows. But let me throw out some suggestions.

1. Make sure the subquery `SELECT F4111.orderID+1 ...` is fast. If not, then view your database's query execution plan to see where the time is being spent. You might need to index the `orderDATE` column. If `orderTYPE` is indexed alone you might want to either remove that or add another column to the index to improve its cardinality.
2. If the subquery isn't the problem then things are a bit murky because the simplest explanation is also the unlikeliest: that there either is no index on `orderID` or the database query engine is choosing not to use that index. Worth checking. Again, learning how to view your database's query execution plans will help you pinpoint the problem.
3. It would be straightforward to rewrite your query to use an inner join rather than `IN (SELECT ...)` but there's no particular reason to expect that to help. Still, you could try it. If it works, it would be worth your time to compare the execution plans of both that and the original SQL.

(You may have sensed a recurring theme to these suggestions.)

4. It is possible for data or indices to become unhealthy over time; consult your database vendor's documentation on topics like fragmentation and index tuning. But this is not likely to be the issue, and its usually left to DBAs to detect and diagnose such problems.